# Angular httpClient cannot read property undefined of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have an Object which makes up the content of my nav. The object is obtained with a get() request, which sits inside the ngOnInit() function of the navigation component. With the following code, the navigation functions appears to work fine:

```
this.httpClient.get(this.url).pipe(map(res => res)).subscribe(res => this.menu = res);
```

However the console is displaying an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
```

The error references a line in the associated HTML: `*ngIf="menu[category]"` but I guess for a fraction of a second, and at the point in time the HTML is rendered, the menu object does not exist so I see this error. Am I doing something wrong here? I must be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. The template renders before the `menu` property is initialized and so it throws an error.

There are multiple ways to solve this.

1. Wrap the template in a `*ngIf` check.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!!menu">
  <div *ngIf="menu?.category">
    ...
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

2. Use safe navigation operator

```html
<div *ngIf="menu?.category">
  ...
</div>
```

3. Using `async` pipe. This would also remove the overhead of handling a subscription in the controller.

Controller (*.ts)

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  menu$: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menu$ = this.httpClient.get(this.url);
  }
}
```

Template (*.html)

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(menu$ | async) as menu">
  <div *ngIf="menu.category">
    ...
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: `menu?.category` is not the same as `menu?.[category]`. but author of the question could also be wrong in that

Comment: @Andrei My menu is an object with nested objects and arrays

Comment: then take Michael's answer, but replace `?.category` to `?.[category]`

Comment: @Andrei: I wouldn't say so. It must be either dot-notation or bracket notation. You can't mix them. And AFAIK, the safe-navigation operator only works with dot-notation. Is it possible to make a minimal reproducible example for the `?.[category]` notation?

Comment: @Dan: Then I'd say it's better to either go with option 1 or 3. With option 2 you need to replace all the property fetch with safe-navigation operator.

Comment: true. for some reason I thought it is possible